# Python searching patterns in lists of strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, select

I have a list of strings like the following in Python:

```
         SS = ['T', 'Q', 'T', 'D', 'Q', 'D', 'D', 'Q', 'T', 'D']
```

Is there anyway I could check how many Ts are directly followed by D, so in this case, there are 2 Ts (second and the last T) that meet the requirement.

I tried this but it was not working though, any advice? thx!

```
            if ['T','Q'] in SS:
                 print ("yes")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this iteratively checking if the next character was a `D` and implementing some sort of counter. This is (probably) the tersest, although maybe not the best way.

```
SS = ['T', 'Q', 'T', 'D', 'Q', 'D', 'D', 'Q', 'T', 'D']
print("".join(SS).count("TD"))
```

Result:

```
2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SS = ['T', 'Q', 'T', 'D', 'Q', 'D', 'D', 'Q', 'T', 'D']
print zip(SS, SS[1:]).count(('T', 'D'))
```

Answer (score 2):

A sequence of single-character strings can be expressed either as your given `list` or as a multi-character string, the main differences being `list` methods vs `str` methods (there's also the `tuple` type), and mutability.

```
>>> SS = ['T', 'Q', 'T', 'D', 'Q', 'D', 'D', 'Q', 'T', 'D']
>>> SS_joined = ''.join(SS)
>>> 'TQ' in SS_joined
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always you re.

```
>>> import re
>>> SS = ['T', 'Q', 'T', 'D', 'Q', 'D', 'D', 'Q', 'T', 'D']
>>> new = ''.join(SS)
>>> len(re.findall('TD',new))
2
```